# What is the difference EdgeCollider from EdgeCollider[] and how to work with EdgeCollider[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose I need an analog to turn off and off the collider(Collider2D.enables)
How should I do it?
In general, I entered all the child objects in the variable and I wanted to turn off the collider to all the child objects, and I got an error:

`('EdgeCollider2D[]' does not contain a definition for 'enabled')`

Comment: The difference is that EdgeCollider is single object and EdgeCollider[] is an array of EdgeCollider objects (many of them). You work with each individual by using iteration function like "for loop". I suggest learning a little more about C#. Also a snippet of code won't hurt also.

Comment: I understood their difference, thank you. But another question remained: how to disable all the child colliders? I recorded the variable so (in the start) `children = GetComponentsInChildren<EdgeCollider2D>();`, then I did `void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D Collider) { 
if(Mathf.CeilToInt(transform.position.y) != Mathf.CeilToInt(EndPoint.position.y)) {
      children.enabled = false;
    }`,
 but I have an error that I wrote in the description of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because GetComponents returns an ARRAY (many objects). You must iterate through them with for loop. For example, children[0].enabled = false; would turn off only ONE (First) item in the array. If you want to turn off all the items in the array you must use for loop / for each, like this:

```
foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.enabled = false;
        }
```